# How to install AAA Certificate Services Root in Ubuntu server

Tags: ios, ubuntu, ssl, certificate, apple-push-notifications

> On March 29, 2021, token and certificate-based HTTP/2 connections to the Apple Push Notification service must incorporate the new root certificate (AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020) which replaces the old GeoTrust Global CA root certificate. To ensure a seamless transition and to avoid push notification delivery failures, verify that both the old and new root certificates for the HTTP/2 interface are included in the Trust Store of each of your notification servers before March 29.

I send push notification from my api Server using [Pushjack](https://github.com/joseph-fox/pushjack). My server is Ubuntu (14.04). How can I include this new certificate in my Server?

Comment: any updates on this?